# Prevent display from turning off with certain applications

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, display, automation

I have a MacBook Pro, and during media presentations, my screen automatically turns off according to the settings app (which of course is operation as usual, to be expected).

I'm looking for an Applescript, setting, app, commandline command, etc. that could disable the auto screen shutoff per app rather than constantly having to change the setting globally. I've already looked for a setting within the app itself (ProPresenter, in this case) with no luck. I'm also okay if the solution bases its action on the presence or absence of a second display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Amphetamine](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12)  (which Chris mentioned in a comment) makes it trivial to automatically disable sleep whenever some app is running or frontmost. From what I see online, I'm not sure Caffeine has that feature.

Answer (score 4):

[Caffeine](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/caffeine/id411246225) is a small free app that can be used to temporarily override Mac settings such as sleep, screen dimming, and screen savers. The app lives in your menu dock, where you can click to turn it on (fill up the coffee cup) before your presentation, and then turn it back off (empty the coffee cup) after your presentation to set your settings back to normal.

Comment: Note that this solution temporarily changes your global Mac settings until you turn it back off (at which point all settings will return to normal). This does **NOT** work on an app-per-app basis.

Comment: Awesome! At the very least I can easily change that global setting using the app. Thanks again! :]

Comment: Too bad it's only available in U.S.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei That is not true. I have done some research and it seems that the creators have pulled the app from the Apple App Store. This means that it is no longer available (in any country) via the App Store. However, you can download the program directly from the creator's website: http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/

Comment: Alternatively, if you prefer to download it from another source or look for alternatives (such as [Amphetamine](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12), which is available from the Apple App Store, in the US and UK at least) , simply Google "caffeine app" and browse through the results.